# How to prevent a listview to overflow under a bottom nav bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want a listview whose bottom ends just above the bottom navigation bar, except my listview's bottom overflows under the navigation bar. Is there a way to constrain the listview to be sandwiched between the appbar and bottom navigation bar?

I have a widget hierarchy that looks like this:

```
Scaffold(
  appbar: ...
  body: Column(
    children: [
      ...
      ListView(...)
    ]
  )
  bottomNavigationBar: ...
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use Expanded for largest widget in Column:

```
Scaffold(
  appbar: ...
  body: Column(
    children: [
      ...
      Expanded(child:ListView(...)),
    ]
  )
  bottomNavigationBar: ...
)
```

Comment: No, this still doesn't give the expected outcome :(

Comment: The original solution was actually correct! Thank you so much Jim Chiu!!

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the scaffold's extendBody [extendBody](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBody.html) property value to false.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(...),
  extendBody: false,
  body: Column(...),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(...)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it might work in your case.

Use SingleChildScrollView in the ListView.
Don't forget to mention the Scroll Direction.

```
Scaffold(
 appbar: ...
  body: Column(
   children: [
    ...
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ListView(...)
    )
   ]
  )
  bottomNavigationBar: ...
)
```

Comment: No, it still gives me the same problem.

Comment: i have disabled the listview physics as ' NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() ' , then wrapped with  'SingleChildScrollView' fixed my solution. Now i have enough space between listview and bottomnavbar.